# Nested Navigation using Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, navigator

I want to implement Nested navigation using GetNavigator, but can't find any proper guide. Anyone with a proper solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add children in the `GetPage` to nest the page inside the parent route.

Example

```html
GetPage(
      name: '/dashboard', 
      page: () => Dashboard(), 
      middlewares: [
        AuthGuard(),
      ],
      children: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/products',
          page: () => Products(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/favorites',
          page: () => Favorites(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/orders',
          page: () => Orders(),
        ),
    ]),
```

Then to navigate to `products` page, you can do

```
Get.toNamed('/dashboard/products');
```

Comment: would this work for a screen with bottom_navigation?

Comment: yes. it should work

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The OP wants to use the `GetNavigator` widget, but your solution uses `GetPage` that only works with the main navigator in `GetMaterialApp`. If someone tries to use `GetPage` with `GetNavigator` it will crash the app.

Comment: Does this load Dashboard and inside the Dashboard, it loads products component? Lets say, my Dashboard page contains a header and a footer. In the body part, it need to render products, favourites and orders - by keeping the same header and footer? Can you please provide a proper example on that?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the first search results on Google, but there were no answers that would satisfy what I needed so here is what I did. This solution applies to the current version of GetX at the time of this writing, **4.6.5**:

1. Create a new file called `destination.dart` that will be responsible for the routing of your nested `Navigator`:

#### destination.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_common/screens/_screens.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

enum Destination {
  // Update these values in the enum with new values that represent the 
  // screens that you want to navigate in your app.
  home,
  countries,
  auth;

  String get route {
    return '/${describeEnum(this)}';
  }

  Widget get widget {
    // Update the cases in this switch for each element of this enum 
    // and the screens that you want to navigate when an enum is selected.
    switch (this) {
      case Destination.home:
        return const HomeScreen();
      case Destination.countries:
        return const CountriesScreen();
      case Destination.auth:
        return const AuthScreen();
    }
  }

  static GetPageRoute getPage(RouteSettings settings) {
    var destination = Destination.values.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.route == settings.name);
    return GetPageRoute(page: () => destination?.widget ?? Container());
  }
}
```

Now it's time to implement the nested navigation:

2. You don't need to use `GetNavigator` to use nested navigators with GetX. You can use simply `Navigator` that comes from `package:flutter/material.dart`.
3. Place the `Navigator` widget under the `GetMaterialApp` (from GetX) tree widget, like in the example below. See the comments in the code for detailed explanation:

#### app.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_common/util/destination.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // GetX Material App. The Navigator must be under this widget tree
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const _Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class _Scaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Scaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Common')),
      // Nested navigator
      body: Navigator(
        // You MUST pass an unique key to the Navigator
        key: Get.nestedKey(1),
        // Initial route (see destination.dart above)
        initialRoute: Destination.home.route,
        // Generate a route based on Destination (see destination.dart above)
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => Destination.getPage(settings),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        height: 72,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- 3.1. You must pass an **unique nested key** to the nested `Navigator`. This can be done with `Get.nestedKey(<some integer>)`.
- 3.2. In `initialRoute` you reference one of the values from `Destination` enum, using the `.route` in the end.
- 3.3. In `onGenerateRoute` you just need to put `(settings) => Destination.getPage(settings)`.

4. In order to navigate to a new screen in the nested navigator you just need to call `Get.toNamed(Destination.auth.route, id: 1)`, for example. This will transition to the `AuthScreen()`.

The first parameter is the route destination, and the second parameter `id` is the unique key that you defined for your nested navigator on step 3.1 above.

Comment: 1) Do arguments work with this method?

Comment: @Sleewok yes, just look at GetX documentation on how you can use either `Get.toNamed(Destionation.home.route, arguments: 'something');` or `Get.to(SomeScreen(someArgument));`