# how can i achieve same nested navigation in flutter via Getx?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

[image]

Here is a video of navigation in which each tab has the sub-children and then return back to that tab it contains the last page and if we click again on that tab it takes us to the parent page. This app is built with React-Native as in react-native its simple to implement via stack navigator but how is this possible via Getx routing

I have tried IndexedStack in my app bt unable to acheive same functionality. but its not giving me same functionality i want to do it via named routes

Comment: I answered this in another question here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75704334/856979